# Stack height depends on foreground positioned widget

Tags: flutter

Seem that the height of stack equals to the height of background widget

Can it be the height depends on a foreground positioned widget?

```
Stack(
  children: [
        // Background widget
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),
        // Foreground widget
        Positioned(
          top: 20,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Container(
             // some dynamic content with dynamic height
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Just add the stack as the child of the container and give it a padding top of 20.

Comment: actually i wrapped the stack inside a singleScrollview ...there is problematic to use a fixed value as  the Foreground widget got dynamic height,